# MySQL GROUP BY only values where all match WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I need to get a list of the numbers where all rows with finished = 1.
For example the correct list is here: 2,5

```
  id | number | finished
-------------------------
  0  | 1      | 0
  1  | 2      | 1
  2  | 2      | 1
  3  | 3      | 0
  4  | 3      | 1
  5  | 3      | 1
  6  | 4      | 1
  7  | 4      | 0
  8  | 4      | 0
  9  | 5      | 1
```

This query don´t work:

```
SELECT numbers 
WHERE finished = 1 
GROUP BY number;
```

the result is `2,3,4,5` because one row will match, but I need only the number when all rows of one number matches.

// EDIT

the Code from the answers worked well, but now I have a new but nearly the same problem.
Now I what to filter by 2 columns

```
id | number | finished | fixed
-------------------------------
0  | 1      | 0        | 1
1  | 2      | 1        | 1
2  | 2      | 1        | 1
3  | 3      | 1        | 0
4  | 3      | 1        | 1
5  | 3      | 1        | 1
6  | 4      | 1        | 1
7  | 4      | 0        | 0
8  | 4      | 0        | 1
9  | 5      | 1        | 1
```

The needed result is: `number = 2,5`

Now the where clause must be `WHERE finished = 1 AND fixed = 1`

Answer (score 3):

You can use aggregation like this:

```
SELECT number
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY number
HAVING MIN(finished) = 1
```

I assume `finished` can only be `0` or `1`.

Comment: This is by far the smartest way to do this. Nice.

Comment: This has been such a huge help after a couple of days of searching how to do something similar, and once I've seen it, it's blindingly obvious!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (I did not tun it)

```
SELECT number WHERE finished = 1 GROUP BY number having count(number) = sum(finished)
```

Comment: why `max(number)`? he wants to get all numbers where all are finished, what does max has to do with it?

Comment: Since you have `GROUP BY number`, `MAX(number)` is the same as just `number`.

Answer (score 1):

What you do is select all numbers where at least one of them is finished=1
If you want all, you need to use something like:

```
SELECT distinct number FROM myTable WHERE finished = 1 and number not in 
  (select number FROM myTable where finished <> 1)
```